# why am i getting sql error 0 with mysql 8?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb, percona

i can't seem to figure it out why i'm getting this error i am using percona server for mysql 8 with sql mode set to `sql_mode = "NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"`

this is the error i am getting whats sql error 0 ?

```
 MySQL: Invalid Query: 
            SELECT
              Rank,
              SpecialRank,
              TotalRank,
              DonationTime,
              RankExpirationTime + INTERVAL 766 HOUR
            FROM users_donor_ranks
            WHERE UserID = '1' SQL error: 0 ()
```

the sql table that i am using

```
CREATE TABLE `users_donor_ranks` (
  `UserID` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Rank` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `DonationTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Hidden` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `TotalRank` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SpecialRank` tinyint(2) DEFAULT '0',
  `InvitesRecievedRank` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `RankExpirationTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UserID`),
  KEY `DonationTime` (`DonationTime`),
  KEY `SpecialRank` (`SpecialRank`),
  KEY `Rank` (`Rank`),
  KEY `TotalRank` (`TotalRank`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

the query i am making

```
G::$DB->query("
        SELECT
          Rank,
          SpecialRank,
          TotalRank,
          DonationTime,
          RankExpirationTime + INTERVAL 766 HOUR
        FROM users_donor_ranks
        WHERE UserID = '$UserID'");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RANK` is [a reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) in MySQL starting version 8.0.2.

You would need to quote this identifier, using backticks:

```
SELECT
    `Rank`,
    SpecialRank,
    TotalRank,
    DonationTime,
    RankExpirationTime + INTERVAL 766 HOUR
FROM users_donor_ranks
WHERE UserID = ?
```

Comment: thank you it worked ;)